# ¿Cómo listar todos los nombres de mis bases de datos y obtener un registro de cada una?

Tags: sql-server

tengo una instancia con 100 bases de datos y en cada base de datos hay una tabla llamada (parametros) y dentro de esa tabla un campo llamado PMNIT que es el nit de cada empresa, lo que requiero es listar en una consulta un listado que me genere el nombre de la base de datos y el nit que le corresponde a cada base de datos, osea el nombre de la base de datos y el nit de cada empresa. son 100 bases.. gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la estructura de la tabla o la consulta que debes repetir?

Comment: de esta forma genero solo el nit de la base de datos, pero me tocaria uno a uno cambiando el nombre de la base de datos:

use MUTUALFUTURO
select PMNIT from parametros

Comment: esta otra consulta me trae el nombre de cada base de datos, pero no se como unir esas dos consultas

SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS [Database], database_id  
FROM sys.databases;

Comment: Qué has intentado? No nos has puesto ejemplos del código que utilizaste

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que necesitas, hay varias opciones. Puedes usar el procedimiento especial `sp_MSforeachdb`. Sin embargo, se sabe que existen problemas en los que puede saltarse bases de datos. También existen programas que permiten correr la misma consulta en múltiples bases de datos y hasta en múltiples servidores al mismo tiempo (por ejemplo: SQL Multi Script de RedGate).

Sin embargo, existe una opción que brinda seguridad y además es gratis. Necesitas usar código dinámico para hacer la consulta a todas las bases de datos. Dejo un ejemplo con bastantes comentarios para explicar el funcionamiento.

```
--Generamos una variable para almacenar el código dinámico
--Y le damos un valor inicial para que no sea nulo
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = '';

--Concatenamos las consultas a todas las bases de datos
--Usamos UNION ALL para que regrese un solo resultado
--Uso corchetes para dar un poco más de seguridad en el nombre de la base de datos
SELECT @SQL += REPLACE(N'UNION ALL
SELECT ''<<nombre_bd>>'' AS nombre_bd, PMNIT from [<<nombre_bd>>]..parametros ', N'<<nombre_bd>>', name)
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4 --Quitamos las bases de datos del sistema
AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1  --Nos aseguramos de tener acceso
AND name LIKE 'PS-%'  --Condiciones adicionales en caso de que haya bases de datos que tengamos que omitir

--Quitamos el primer UNION ALL
SET @SQL = STUFF( @SQL, 1, 10, ''); 

--Esto es solo para ver la instrucción (tiene un límite de caracteres)
PRINT @SQL;

--Executamos el código dinámico
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la explicación, realmente soy un poco nuevo en el tema de consultas y la verdad copie y pegue esa consulta en mi SQL pero no obtengo ningún resultado, perdóname por la ignorancia, podrías explicarme en que forma aplico esa estructura que me diste..... gracias...

Comment: Revisa los comentarios. Nunca debes copiar, pegar y ejecutar un código de internet sin entenderlo (podrías dañar tu sistema si alguien comparte algo inadecuado). Es muy probable que no hayas modificado las condiciones adicionales para mostrar solo ciertas bases de datos. En esta consulta, solo toma las bases de datos que inicien con 'PS-'.